# React Native: All RN components are throwing TS errors

Tags: typescript, react-native

TS2786: 'SafeAreaView' cannot be used as a JSX component.   Its instance type 'SafeAreaView' is not a valid JSX element.

Is just one example of a react native component getting this TS error in my code, I also get it on View, Text etc...

[image]

I think it has something to do with my package.json:

```
    {
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest --passWithNoTests",
    "tsc": "tsc --pretty",
    "check-all": "yarn run tsc && yarn run test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^12.0.0-rc.0",
    "expo": "~42.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "jest-expo": "^48.0.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.21.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.27",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.63.2",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.4.3",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^9.3.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "prettier": "2.8.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.5",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried reloading the editor?

Comment: I had something similar happening to my React native paper text components where it kept thinking it didn’t accept children. Reinstalling RNP fixed it, so if restarting vs code doesn’t work maybe delete your node_modules and run npm i again?

Comment: I only suggest deleting node_modules because I don’t know how expo will behave to having react native reinstalled; but yeah just reinstalling react native (be sure to target the version in your package.json) is an option